# Windowsservercore change time and date

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, windows-server-container

I have a docker running the windowsservercore and I want to change the time in the container to the western European time.

Nothing worked so far

What I tried:

1. Powershell Set-Date

> Set-Date : A required privilege is not held by the

client
 2. using w32tm:

> C:\BuildAgent>net stop w32time The Windows Time service is not
>   started.
>
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.
>
> ====================================================================== Set the SNTP (Simple Network Time Protocol) source for the time server
>
> C:\BuildAgent>w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual
>   /manualpeerlist:"0.it.pool.ntp.org 1.it.pool.ntp.org 2.it.pool.ntp.org
>   3.it.pool.ntp.org" The command completed successfully.
>   ============================================= ... and then turn on the time service back on
>
> C:\BuildAgent>net start w32time System error 1058 has occurred.
>
> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or
>   because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
>
> ============================================= Tell the time sync service to use the changes
>
> C:\BuildAgent>w32tm /config /update The following error occurred: The
>   service has not been started. (0x80070426)
>   ======================================================= Reset the local computer's time against the time server
>
> C:\BuildAgent>w32tm /resync /rediscover The following error occurred:
>   The service has not been started. (0x80070426)

Can somone help me? Maybe there is also an option in docker doing this?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/308188/ntp-sync-on-windows-7